# Scene loaded from .rcproject file doesn't show up in .nonAR mode on real iPhone device

Tags: ios, swiftui, realitykit, reality-composer

I am trying to create a 3D scene for an iOS app using an rcproject file output from RealityComposer.

I tried to display a Scene loaded from a .rcproject file in ARView with .nonAR mode. The code is as follows.
I have confirmed that the simulators display the scene properly.

But scene is not displayed on my actual iPhone8 and iPhone12 mini (Both iOS 16.03).

I am puzzled why scene loaded from .rcproject file does not show up with my actual device. If anyone has had the similar experience or has an idea of the cause, I would appreciate it.

Thank you for taking the time to read this post.

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
 
    //  if cameramode is ".ar", work properly
    let arview = ARView(frame: .zero, cameraMode: .nonAR)

    Sample.loadMySceneAsync { (result) in

        do {

            let myScene = try result.get()

            arview.scene.anchors.append(myScene)

        } catch {

            print("Failed to load myScene")

        }

    }
    
    let camera = PerspectiveCamera()

    let cameraAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0, 0.2, 0.5])

    cameraAnchor.addChild(camera)

    arView.scene.addAnchor(cameraAnchor)

    return arview
}


func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
}
```